# Content not showing in Joomla modules

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I build a simple client site in Joomla last summer.

http://squirtz.ca

Somewhere along the line, after the site had been completed, the content stopped showing up in the modules. The menus don't show up, the polls modules doesn't show up, nothing. The funny thing is that the headings of the modules show, but not the content.

I have searched for a while now, trying to find a solution other than a fresh reinstall of Joomla, so any thoughts or advice would be really appreciated!

My thoughts:

1. The database may have been corrupted.
2. There may have been an auto-update by the host (GoDaddy) that caused the break (highly unlikely)
3. There may have been a change in the server that's causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You did not install or change anything in the mean time?

More info on your setup would be helpful. Did you install and/or use non-default extensions? Components, modules, plugins? Maybe godaddy provide non-joomla-defaults by default? You even tagged this question with joomla-extensions, but did not provide ANY info on your setup.

Check in your admin section in your modules section the modules, that and which ones are active, and what settings they use (e.g. what they shall show). Check that the things displayed on your sites are the modules you expect, and not part of your theme. Maybe the modules are not shown at all.

As you suggested your DB be the issue, connect to it and check the tables. MySQL can check its db itself. Try a mysqldump and check your data is there.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try installing a xamp on your own pc, and transferring the website there to see if its something to do with your host.

Comment: Thanks. I've replicated the site locally, and have no issues seeing content with the modules. Contacting the hosting company.